# Global vs. local scope at `(new Function()).call(...)`

Tags: javascript, function, scope, eval, global

my Problem seems to be in my [module.js](https://kekse.biz/js/web/module.js).

It seems the `evaluateJavaScript()` function calls my script modules correctly:
the `this` in the module is a reference to the `new Module()` object (within `Module.session`).

BUT when I declare variables or constants in this modules, they seem to go global (both `const`
and `var`, but also `let`..). AFAIR when declaring variables/constants within functions, they
won't be global..

Don't really know what's the problem.. I could imagine a workaround by replacing any `var` etc.
in the script code string by `this.. =`  or smth., but this depends on the value types. And I
also thought about defining the module environment by passing arguments to the functions, but
then I needed to set them to a real value - they can't be defined with getters or so.. this way
I reside in the *old* states.. don't I?

Would be happy about any help with it. Regards, the Cake.

After `eval()` with changed code strings (closures around, etc.) I came to the `new Function()`,
which works really great. But the problem stays: declaring vars/consts go global..

//edit
You're asking for more code. So here you are:

```
    static evaluateJavaScript(_code, _module, ... _params)
    {
        if(typeof _code !== 'string') return error('Invalid % argument', null, '_code');
        else if((_code = _code.trim()).startsWith('javascript:')) _code = _code.substr(11);
        if(!Object._isObject(_module)) _module = Module.getSession(_module, ... _params);
        const args = Module.getArguments(_module, _params);
        const argKeys = new Array(args.length); const argValues = new Array(args.length);
        for(var i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) { argKeys[i] = args[i][0]; argValues[i] = args[i][1]; }
        const func = new Function(... argKeys, Module.wrapJavaScriptCode(_code, _module, ... _params));
        try { _module.result = func.call(_module, ... argValues); _module.error = null; }
        catch(_error) { _module.result = undefined; _module.error = _error; error(_error); }
        return Object.null({ module: _module, result: _module.result, error: _module.error, code: _code });
    }
```

//edit @ Bergi: "**Please provide a minimal reproducible example**":

https://jsfiddle.net/nyL35gab/

But now I'm wondering.. why this doesn't work here!? In the fiddle it perfectly worx! :-/

```js
const Context = { id: null };

const getContext = (_module) => {
  const result = Context;
  result.id = _module;
  return result;
};

const evaluate = (_code, _module) => {
  const ctx = getContext(_module);
  const func = new Function('context', 'id', _code);
  return ctx.result = func.call(ctx, ctx, _module);
};

const code = `var output = document.getElementById('test');` +
    `console.log('this: ' + output.constructor.name);` +
  `console.log('id: ' + id);`;


console.log(typeof output);
evaluate(code, 'test');
console.log(typeof output);//at my kekse.biz this would be the <div> node! :-/
```

```html
<div id="test"><p>hm, here it works. don't know what's wrong about
<a href="https://kekse.biz/" target="_blank"><b>kekse.biz</b></a>
@ <a href="https://kekse.biz/js/web/module.js" target="_blank">module.js</a>
or <a href="https://kekse.biz/js/web/page.js" target="_blank">page.js</a>,
or even <a href="https://kekse.biz/js/web/html.js" target="_blank">html.js</a>...? :-/</p>
<p><u>JFYI</u>: the 2nd `<i>console.log(typeof output);</i>` shows `<i>undefined</i>`,
which is great. but here it is suddenly the &lt;div&gt; node.. :-(</p></div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: new Function creates a function in the global/root scope so everything should be passed as arguments to it.

Comment: @ Alexander: but I'm doing a `.call(..)` with the correct `_module` as context, and it works, as it seems: in the module `this` is a reference to the `_module`..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ Bergi: edited my post above.

Comment: @Sebastian That not exactly *minimal*… Can you post all the code that is necessary to reproduce the problem [in your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1048572), please, preferably as a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/1048572)?

Comment: `eval` evaluates in global context, not local contenxt. Also, _dont use eval_. How is it 2023 and people are still doing this.

Comment: I'm NOT using `eval()`, here's a `new Function(...).call(...)`. Just added a 'JSFiddle'..

Comment: @Sebastian Can you include that JSFiddle as a Stack Snippet, please? I, for one, find it quite difficult to access JSFiddles these days (though it used to be the best website ever).

Comment: ok, it's done [great invention! :-]

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks for the update, but that code does not reproduce the problem. It outputs `undefined` `this: HTMLDivElement` `id: test` `undefined` as expected.

Comment: yes, as i wrote.. i don't know where the problem is here. :-/